# WMIC process call start not working remotely

Tags: batch-file

Here's the info: Currently we're working on how to execute a batch file on another server, but since we're on research and testing phase we're currently working on our client PC. I tried to run using this command:

```
wmic /user:<username> /password:<password> /node:<machine_name> process call create "cmd /c E:\sharedfolder\try_wmic.bat"
```

Is it necessary to work on this by an administrator account, or did I miss something?

Thanks and I appreciate all your feedback :)

Comment: What does `E:\sharedfolder\try_wmic.bat` do and what do you expect it to do? Is it stored on the remote machine? Do you see an errormessage?

Comment: yes it's on remote machine, In the batch file there is a command that calls a vbscript. we're trying to execute it using batch file from Comp A to Comp B. Unfortunately there's no error message shown. only this .Executing <Win32_Process>-> Create(). Method Execution Succesfully

Comment: `Method execution successful.` is what you'd expect to see - I'd try to redirect the vbscript's output into a file and inspect that to see what happens. Be sure to use an absolute file name, i.e. `... > c:\temp\script.log`.

Comment: Remote programs are invisible. You don't need to be an admin to run `wmic` however it does require an admin to run it once before non admins can use it. You still have whatever security restrictions you have. If E: is a mapped drive, mapping is done per security token. Admins have two security tokens limited and elevated. Drives mapped limited are only available when not elevated.

Comment: The modern way to refer to network drives is via UNC. `\\Servername\Sharename\foldername\filename.ext`

Comment: Hi Noodles, so you mean on the first run to be able to successfully run this is I have to use a admin? Also we can't use UNC on this one because we need to open an excel on a remote server, the other server doesn't have installed excel, that's why we need to trigger it remotely to the other server.

Comment: WMIC requires a administrator to run it once on any machine you run it on. Windows programs understand UNC, drive letters was replaced by UNC 20 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

wmic created processes start with no network privileges.  Even attempting to use UNC network paths can fail if you are accessing a Windows 10 machine.  Something like the following will work:

```
wmic /node:"computername" process call create "cmd.exe /c (net use /user:\"DOMAIN\AdminUser\" x: \\machine\share \"YourPassword\" && dir x:\ && net use x: /delete ) > c:\test.txt"
```

With the obvious caveat that you are passing credentials in plain text.

The issue is that in order to create a process on another machine you need elevated privileges, and with elevated privileges your normal network mappings are no longer available.  It is as though there are two different admin users: one when the admin user is doing normal things and another when the admin user invokes those privileges (for instance to create a process on another machine).

As an example of the issue, if you did not remove the drive mapping to X: as I did in my example and targeted a Windows 10 machine with that command, a normal user might see the mapping, but would be unable to use it: 'net use' would show the drive was 'Unavailable' and attempting to access it would result in 'The system cannot find the path specified'.